# What will be resumption order when notifyAll() calls?

Tags: java, types

```
static Integer sync = 1;

static void m() throws Exception {
    synchronized (sync) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        sync.wait(1000L);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

    }
}

static void mthd() throws Exception {
    synchronized (sync) {
        System.out.println("Notifying...");
        sync.notify();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                m();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable t = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                m();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable g = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mthd();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread th1 = new Thread(r);
    Thread th2 = new Thread(t);
    Thread th3 = new Thread(g);
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
}
```

The code produce the following output:

```
Thread-0
Thread-1
Notifying...
Thread-0
Thread-1
```

That is, we have the same order as the order of adding to wait-set or it doesn't specified?

Comment: What makes you think it might be deterministic?

Comment: @wallyk I don't know. I just ask is it true...

Comment: Threading is inherently non-deterministic. You shouldn't rely on the ordering of execution of threads

Comment: `notify` just marks the threads as able to be run. It's up to the scheduler which ones to run when. Thus, it's unspecified.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't synchronize on an autoboxed object, as some of them are cached; this can lead to subtle deadlocks between different parts of your application that just happen to be synchronizing on the same object.  String literals (which get interned) also have this problem.  Just do `Object lock = new Object();` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [notify() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--):

> If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation.

And [notifyAll() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--):

> The awakened threads will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened threads enjoy no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object.

So not only do waiting threads not awake in order, a thread that wasn't previously waiting but wanted the lock for another reason (say, calling a `synchronized` method) might get the lock first.

Answer (score 3):

The notifying order isn't specified so any of the threads can execute at that time. This is all up to the thread scheduler to when each one should execute.